# Does query and second level cache works in synchronization?

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache, query-cache

i am using both second level cache and query cache. Here is the code snippet

```
//first block
session = factory.openSession();
company1=(Company)session.get(Company.class, 1);
session.close();

//second block
session = factory.openSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query updateQuery=session.createQuery("update Company set companyName = 'newCompany' where companyId=1");
updateQuery.setCacheable(true);
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();

//Third block
session = factory.openSession();
company1=(Company)session.get(Company.class, 1); // line 1
session.close();
```

In second block i did update in query . In third block i am getting the company record thru second level cache. What i was expecting i will get the same result(in 3rd block) what i got in first block but i got the updated record (done by query update in 2nd block) i.e "newCompany" at line 1

So looks like query cache and second level cache are in synch with
each other as update done by query cache is picked by  second level cache.

**UPDATE:-**
So How does query and second level cahe works in synch? I mean does query cache first check
under second level cache whether there has been any update  for the given query parameter?

Comment: I don't think setting an update query cacheable has any effect. select queries can be cacheable, to tell Hibernate to retrieve its results from the cache if it's rexecutedwith the same parameters. I don't get your question. Of course Hibernate tries its best to make sure queries return correct results. If you change the value of an entity, the cache will be updated or flushed.

Comment: @JB Nizet which part is not clear in my question. See my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query cache stores IDs returned by previous executions of a cacheable *select* query.

Let's say you execute the following cacheable query:

```
select line from OrderLine line join line.order order 
where line.status = ? and order.date = ?
```

If you execute it once, Hibernate will store the IDs of the lines returned by the query in its query cache. And it will store the lines themselves in the second-level cache.

If you execute the same query a second time, with the same parameters, Hibernate will extract the IDs from the query cache, without executing the select query. Then it will get every line by ID (which should be fast since the lines are in the second-level cache)

If you insert, update or delete a line or an order, Hibernate will detect it. Since this modification could affect the result of the cached query, the cache entries associated with this query in the query cache will be evicted. So the nexttime you execute this query again, it will be executed against the database, and the results will be stored again in the query cache.

Comment: you said "Hibernate will store the IDs of the lines returned by the query in its query cache. And it will store the lines themselves in the second-level cache" what are the ids and lines in the query you mentioned? Actually i did not get what Ids/lines meant in your statement?

Comment: The query selects entities of type OrderLine. The lines are the instances of OrderLine returned by the query "select **line** from...". The IDs are the IDs of these entities.

Comment: So it means its mandatory to enable second level cache to use query cache. Can't query cache be used without second level cache?

Comment: It can, but it will probably make things much slower. Even with the second-level cache on, unless it's used for queries that almost never change, the query cache isn't so useful.

Comment: To me looks like its not possible to use query cache without second level cache. The reason is as soon as as i remove @Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE) from entity company to disable 2nd level cache, query cache does not work also. Is something wrong in my understanding?

Comment: That surprises me. But as I said, using the query cache without the second level cache is a bad idea anyway, since it will make things much slower. Why would you want that?